# How to select only folder not files using FBean oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have sample oracle form AWTFileDialog in which open dialog box and select files but I want user select only folder and get all files inside folder.

**Code:**

```
:BL.FILE := FBean.Invoke_Char('CTRL.BEAN', 1, 'openFile' ,'Open a file...,C:\');
```

I am using oracle forms 11g

How to achieve this target

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `webutil_file` package of `webutil.pll` which should be attached, and the object library `webutil.olb` should be imported by subclassing to the forms before proceeding with the program. After all, consider to write the following code :

```
Declare
    v_dir varchar2(500);
Begin    
  Client_Tool_Env.Getvar('WINDIR',v_dir); 
 :BL.FILE := webutil_file.file_open_dialog(v_dir,'myblock','*.*','Open a file...'); 
End;
```